# Email sent recieving in spam

Tags: email, subdomain, spam

I am using subdomain for sending email. for example test.example.com. I have configured DMARC,SPF,MX record, Reverse DNS. Checked with mxtoolbox.com and seems perfect.Also checked the IP for blacklist and non of them blacklisted My IP but when I send mail it recieves in Spam folder in my Gmail account. My server is hosted with Digital ocean ubuntu server. It will be helpful if some one give their suggestion

Comment: In my experience, implementing DKIM and Reverse DNS helps (sometimes a lot). However, Google also evaluates the contents of your email to determine a SPAM rating. Google even puts some of their own email in my Gmail SPAM folder.

Comment: Add header details of received email for better examining.